# Master Detail splitApp is empty on mobile viewer 5SAPUI5°

Tags: sapui5

I am a beginner in sapui5. I'm working on a sapui5 project with splitApp architecture.

I am wondering why the Master view works correctly on a desktop machine, but is empty on a mobile device.

Master.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="query.sap.controller.Master" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
<SplitContainer>
    <masterPages>
        <semantic:MasterPage title="Query List">
            <semantic:content>
                <!-- For client side filtering add this to the items attribute:  parameters: {operationMode: 'Client'}}" -->
                <List id="table" width="auto" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" 
                items="{ path: '/QueriesSet', sorter : { path : 'Cubename', group : true }
            }"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <SearchField width="80%" search="onSearchQuery"/>
                            <Button icon="sap-icon://refresh" press="onRefresh"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <items>
                        <ObjectListItem press="onListItempress" type="Active" title="  {Queryname}" intro="Query name : ">
                            <firstStatus>
                                <ObjectStatus text="{GenerationTime}"/>
                            </firstStatus>
                            <secondStatus>
                                <ObjectStatus state="Warning" title="Created By " text="{CreatedBy}"/>
                            </secondStatus>
                        </ObjectListItem>
                    </items>
                </List>
            </semantic:content>
        </semantic:MasterPage>
    </masterPages>
</SplitContainer>
```

On desktop:

[image]

On mobile:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your code? Which theme is used?

Comment: Hi martin 
I used sap_bluecrystal theme and you'll find master code in xml view  below